# css: misunderstanding of how id rules are passed down?

Tags: css

I was having a trouble of getting ul markers to fall inside the margin.  I fixed it by changing

```
#contents ul {
border:solid;
    font-size:85%;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-left: 2.5em;
    max-width: inherit;
list-style-position: inside;
}
```

to

```
ul {
  /* rules */
}
```

Even though the ul in question is given the id of 'contents' it seems the rules only get passed down to its children?  Or is there another reason for this mishap?  I'd like to be able to limit the ul ruleset to the 'contents' id if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
#contents ul
```

You're saying any `<ul>` that is a descendent of and element with `id="contents"` should be applied the styles. But you say you have

```
<ul id="contents">
```

so you can do

```
ul#contents {
  /* your rules */
}
```

Though this shouldn't be necessary to qualify the selector with an element; `#contents` alone should be enough.

If you want both the `<ul>` with `id="contents"` **and** it's descendents, you can do

```
#contents, #contents ul {
  /* your rules */
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think part of the broken layout was caused by elements with a different id being nested within.  Would that override the parent id so that the styles for that id wouldn't get applied any longer?

Comment: I can't really say without seeing your code, but yes, it's posible.